# Cannot find module 'iconv'

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp

After I installed gulp,I execute the following command

I tried following steps,

> 1.npm install

versions
 npm    :- 6.9.0,
 node   :- 10.15.13,
 python :- 2.7.10

> 2.npm install gulp

versions
CLI version   :- 3.9.1,
Local version :- 3.9.1

**And I Also tried globaly,its also showing same error**

```
> npm install -g gulp
```

After Install gulp in above version and run the following command

`gulp like`

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'iconv'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (C:\cygwin64\home\D-218\workspace\shima\src\tasks\json.js:4:14)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)

Comment: Windows or Mac? Try sudo yarn install instead if npm doesn't work

Comment: I use windows 10 64 bit

Comment: i was having problem on windows when using npm but i changed to yarn. See if it works for you. -> sudo yarn install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only installed Gulp on you system. Gulp is a task runner. One of your tasks requires using iconv. The error is showing the module "iconv" is not found. Install it with the below, add "-g" if you want install system wide rather than just in this project directory.

```
npm install iconv
```

Then in your gulp file import iconv with a line as follows:

```
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
```

Rerun your task and it should execute fine.

Comment: Problem Solved,Thanks for replying